# Using ASCII Formfeed (FF) \f showing symbol instead of return indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python 3 and trying to use formfeed \f, however when I type this code I get a symbol instead.

I'm using Python 3.6.1 and have already verified checking the version and path with power shell.

IDE I'm using is Visual Studio Code with no plug-ins.

Here's the code I'm running...

```
print("I'm using form\ffeed")
```

The output I'm getting is this...

```
I'm using form♀feed
```

Comment: What exactly are you running the script in? The Windows cmd console, a powershell window, the IDE console? Whatever you are printing to doesn't support form-feeds. This is not a Python issue.

Comment: /questions/27234564/ide-output-different-from-command-line

Comment: @MartijnPieters In the description I put that I'm using IDE Visual Studio Code and PowerShell. I'm executing the code from PowerShell.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've also tried windows command prompt and I'm getting the same output. I'm using windows 8.1.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've changed IDEs via Atom and Pycharm. I've got the same results with Atom.
With PyCharm I didn't use powershell or windows command prompt. I just ran it from the IDE and now from there I get an arrow pointing up.

Comment: @PaulLaguna: like this then? [Formfeed (\f) and vertical tab (\v) not working in C](//stackoverflow.com/q/21184548) Again, this is not a Python issue. I'm not currently aware of any Windows consoles that support the formfeed character. Why do you need it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the quick reply. 
I understand fully what you say and now know that this isn't a Python issue after posting this question thanks to you. It all makes sense.
I'm teaching myself Python and learning about escape sequences.
A few of my colleges are using the same IDE, typing the same code, and using powershell to run the code, so I was trying to figure out why my code was different from theirs. I was hoping that I was doing something wrong when running the code. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes the link that you've provided is exactly what's happening to me. I haven't confirmed that if my colleges are running Mac, Linux or Windows. But thanks for the link again, that pretty much explains why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you are printing *to* (the Windows console, IDE console, or whatever Python stdout is connected to when you run your code) doesn't support form feeds.

You are using the character correctly, but that doesn't mean that whatever you write the character to will know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what terminal you use dictates what you're going to get.